# transponse and convert an array with mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

Any tips how to make this to generate to required output?

Also, would worth/possible to make it one line without the intermediary assignment?

```
const matches = 
[
  {id: 1, bd: "a"},
  {id: 2, bd: "b"},
  {id: 4, bd: "e"},
  {id: 3, bd: "c"}
];
// ideal output would be { ids: [1,2,4,2], bds: ["a", "b", "e", "c"] }
// but I could only get to [[1,2,4,3],["a","b","e","c"]]

    let matchArgs;
    matchArgs = matches.map((match) => 
             [match.id, match.bd]);

    console.log("1.", matchArgs);

    matchArgs = matchArgs[0].map((match, i) => matchArgs.map(row => row[i]));

    console.log("2:", matchArgs)
```

[Runnable code](https://es6console.com/jckfj1ga/)

Comment: `matchArgs = { ids: matches.map(i => i.id), bds: matches.map(i => i.bd) };`

Comment: what if key names are unknown?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Then the answer is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` method to return object as a result.

```js
const matches =  [
  {id: 1, bd: "a"},
  {id: 2, bd: "b"},
  {id: 4, bd: "e"},
  {id: 3, bd: "c"}
];

const result = matches.reduce((r, {id, bd}) => {
  r.ids = (r.ids || []).concat(id)
  r.bds = (r.bds || []).concat(id)
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce`

```
var output = matches.reduce((a, c) => (
   a.ids.push( c.id ), 
   a.bds.push( c.bd ), a
), {
  ids:[],
  bds:[]
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var matches = 
[
  {id: 1, bd: "a"},
  {id: 2, bd: "b"},
  {id: 4, bd: "e"},
  {id: 3, bd: "c"}
];

var output = matches.reduce((a, c) => (a.ids.push(c.id), a.bds.push(c.bd), a), {
  ids:[],
  bds:[]
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @ChrisG I realized the same as well. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var result = matches.reduce((obj, currentObj) => {
  obj.ids.push(currentObj.id);
  obj.bds.push(currentObj.bd);
  return obj;
}, {ids: [], bds: []});
```

**Demo:**

```js
const matches = 
[
  {id: 1, bd: "a"},
  {id: 2, bd: "b"},
  {id: 4, bd: "e"},
  {id: 3, bd: "c"}
];

var result = matches.reduce((obj, currentObj) => {
 obj.ids.push(currentObj.id);
  obj.bds.push(currentObj.bd);
  return obj;
}, {ids: [], bds: []});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic approach without knowing the keys in advance by iterating the keys and building a new property if necessary for the wanted array of values.

You could omit the `+ 's'` for generating the key if not necessary.

```js
var matches = [{ id: 1, bd: "a" }, { id: 2, bd: "b" }, { id: 4, bd: "e" }, { id: 3, bd: "c" }],
    result = matches.reduce(
        (r, o) => (Object.keys(o).forEach(k => (r[k + 's'] = r[k + 's'] || []).push(o[k])), r),
        {}
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```